# Firefox is throttling setInterval

Tags: javascript, firefox, setinterval

I'm trying to make a web-based game and I use `setInterval` to update the game (positions, collision checks, etc...) 60 times a second.

It works fine in most browsers, but for some reason Firefox *sometimes* throttles it to about 35 times a second. Yes, sometimes. If DevTools is closed, it will throttle, but if you open DevTools and start recording performance, it jumps to 60 and will stay that way until DevTools is closed.

If you're using Firefox, run the snippet and try it:

```js
var cycles = 0;
setInterval(()=>{
  cycles++;
}, 1000/60);
setInterval(()=>{
  console.log("Update cycles per second: %i", cycles);
  cycles = 0;
}, 1000);
```

Is this a bug? If not, why does this happen and how can I work around it?

**Edit:** I'm not using `setInterval` to render. For that I use `requestAnimationFrame`. I'm using `setInterval` to update the game at a *constant time interval*, because `requestAnimationFrame` fires before repainting, and is heavily dependent on the refresh rate of the user's screen.

Comment: Yes, don't use seInterval for animations.   Use requestAnnimatonFrame instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: *`heavily dependent on the refresh rate of the user's screen`* - why would you bother updating faster than that?

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/175934/206310

Comment: I could also update the game as many times as needed in the `requestAnimationFrame` callback (maybe I will), but then the user inputs would be delayed until the next repaint. For example, a square moves 1 px/update while a key is being held down. If the user has a 30Hz screen, holding the key down for 1/6th of a second would either not move the square at all (if `requestAnimationFrame` didn't fire while the key was being held down) or move it 2px (if it did). (Btw sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on timers being accurate. They often aren't. Instead, rely on *time* being accurate:

```
 var cycles = 0, start = Date.now();
 setInterval(() => {
  cycles = Math.floor((Date.now() - start) / 1000 * 60);
 }, 1000/60);
```

That said, [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is probably a better choice for your use than `setInterval`, as it gets called on every rerender.

Comment: @D.Pardal well 30fps is enough for that, isn't it? Also have a look at this [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection#Video_games)